# Заполнение квадратной матрицы по спирали от центра против часовой стрелки(решено)

Tags: java, массивы

Помогите заполнить двумерный массив (размер A x A). Из углов сделал, а из центра никак, уже запутался в индексах.

Мой код:

```
int n = 5;
    int A[][] = new int[n][n];

int i=n*n,j,k,p=n/2;
System.out.println(p);

for(k=1;k<=p;k++)/*Цикл по номеру витка*/
{
   for (j=n-1;j>=k;j--) A[j][k-1]=i--;/* --//-- по левому вертикальному столбцу*/

   for (j=k-1;j<n-k+1;j++) A[k-1][j]=i--;/*Определение значений верхнего гор столбца*/

   for (j=k;j<n-k+1;j++) A[j][n-k]=i--;/* --//-- По правому вертикальному столбцу*/

   for (j=n-k-1;j>k;j--) A[n-k][j]=i--;/* --//-- по нижнему горизонтальному столбцу*/
}

if(n%2 == 1)
    A[p][p] = 1;
 
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.format("%5d",A[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}


Ну вот решил, работает правильно. Может кому-то будет полезным=)    

    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[][] = new int[size][size];

    int halfsize = size/2,counter=size*size;
    for(int i = 0;i<halfsize;i++){

        for(int j = size-i-1;j>i;j--) arr[j][i] = counter--;

        for(int j = i;j<=size-i-1;j++) arr[i][j] = counter--;

        for(int j = i+1;j<=size-i-1;j++) arr[j][size-1-i] = counter--;

        for(int j = size-2-i;j>i;j--) arr[size-1-i][j] = counter--;
    }

    if(size%2 == 1)
        arr[halfsize][halfsize] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.format("%5d",arr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Для наглядности картинка:

[image: Должно получиться нечто подобное=)]

Comment: Если у Вас возникли трудности с Вашим кодом - приведите пример кода и Вам очень быстро помогут, но за Вас писать не будут. От меня минус пока.

Comment: добавил код в тему)

Comment: Очень много людей заминусовало Вас еще потому, что вы использовали для тегов неиспользуемые в вашей программе языки: `c++`, `c`. Прошу указать Вас только соответствующие вашему вопросу тэги)

Comment: И написать код для массива 5x5 или для любого размера?

Comment: Спасибо. Метки убрал, размерность(А*А) добавил=)